# How to take down the piracy website that does not respond to DMCAs

Tags: dmca, online-piracy

Suppose that an app developer, A, finds that a website is distributing copies of A's copyrighted app, without permission. A has sent DMCA takedown notices to the site, but has received no response.

Suppose that the site also  hosts Micro$oft apps and apps by other major companies.

Suppose alos that  the site  made some clever download link system where the actual files are downloaded from random servers that are not easy to track.  The  links expire so links cannot be shared to the operators of those download servers:

Comment: You should probably change this to be generic rather than calling out a specific site.

Comment: @DM why would that help?

Comment: @phoog I was thinking it would be less likely to trigger a "legal advice" closure.

Comment: @DM I have made such an edit, in the face of some votes to close.

Comment: @DM I don't suppose that the identity of the copyright pirate has much bearing on whether the question is a request for legal advice.

Comment: @phoog In the meta post ["Policy for questions that clearly ask for specific legal advice"](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/policy-for-questions-that-clearly-ask-for-specific-legal-advice/222#222) it says: "If you can edit the question to make it a question that asks for general legal *information* while preserving the original author's meaning, then you should edit rather than close." I'm satisfied that this has been done.

Answer (score 4):

If a website takes down something that infringes on your copyright because of a DMCA request, the legal effect is that you can’t sue the website, only the person who put the content on the website.

If a website doesn’t respond to a DMCA request, then you can sue the person responsible AND the website. And that’s what you would have to do: Sue them.

And in extreme cases copyright infringement can be criminal; in that case the police might go after the website.